# jQuery Isotope additive (greater than) filters

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, filter, jquery-isotope

it`s my first question here on SO so: "Hello World".

My question:
I`m developing wordpress theme using Isotope jQuery plugin. I managed to add some additive filters (terms and other fields). The only trouble I have is adding another two filters "Height" and "Width" that will "overlap" with rest of filters. The filters should check if Height value is smaller than 50 in example. Same with Width. I tried to implement the filters from Isotope documentation, but these result in 0 items displayed :/

Below is my actual init of Isotope.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

$(window).load( function() {

var $container = $('.grid').isotope({
            masonry: {
                columnWidth: '.grid-sizer',
                gutter: '.gutter-sizer',
            },
            itemSelector: '.grid-item',
            percentPosition: true,
});

var $output = $('#output');

// filter with selects and checkboxes
var $selects = $('#filters select');
var $checkboxes = $('#filters input');

$selects.add( $checkboxes ).change( function() {
  // map input values to an array
  var exclusives = [];
  var inclusives = [];
  // exclusive filters from selects
  $selects.each( function( i, elem ) {
    if ( elem.value ) {
      exclusives.push( elem.value );
    }
  });
  // inclusive filters from checkboxes
  $checkboxes.each( function( i, elem ) {
    // if checkbox, use value if checked
    if ( elem.checked ) {
      inclusives.push( elem.value );
    }
  });

  // combine exclusive and inclusive filters

  // first combine exclusives
  exclusives = exclusives.join('');

  var filterValue;
  if ( inclusives.length ) {
    // map inclusives with exclusives for
    filterValue = $.map( inclusives, function( value ) {
      return value + exclusives;
    });
    filterValue = filterValue.join(', ');
  } else {
    filterValue = exclusives;
  }

  $output.text( filterValue );
  $container.isotope({ filter: filterValue })
});
```

});

});